# Keeping width ratio between two columns css3

Tags: html, css, width

I want to use media queries to make a responsive website. I have some pages with 2 columns, others with 3 or 4.

For example I have two columns: #colA and #colB. #colA has width 600px, #colB has 360px with a wrapper of 960px width.

I want to use media queries so that if the wrapper has less than 960px, the columns will keep the width proportions between them (which should turn #colA's 600px to 62.5% and #colB's 360px to 37.5% widths..

Is there a way to do this with html/css? If not what are the other (easiest/lightest) options to use with media query?

```
<div id="colA" width="600px">content1</div>
<div id="colB" width="360px">content2</div>
```

to convert in

```
<div id="colA" width="62.5%">content1</div>
<div id="colB" width="37.5%">content2</div>
```

Using css/html?

Edit1: Yes it is a CMS. The user sets the width values in px by dragging some sliders in the control panel. I need to make the template responsive, so when the wrapper's width is less then 960px, the columns will still keep their width proportions between them.

Comment: Sure. Use percentages from the start. To make your life easier, grab one of the many existing responsive grid libraries, such as Boostrap.

Comment: I can't, they are hardcoded in px and can't acces them..

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. "Hardcoded"? Does that mean inline styles? They can usually be overridden. Show some code.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: I know how to override inline values, the problem is elsewhere.. I need to transform pixels to percents dynamically AND also keep the width proportions between the columns inside a wrapper.

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear, but you may need scripting. Is jQuery available?

Answer (score 0):

Your media query should look something like this, just make sure this code sits beneath the previously assigned styles for #colA and #colB

```
@media screen and (max-width: 959px) { 
   #colA{ width:62.5%; }
   #colB{ width:37.5%; }
}
```

Comment: The cols can have any values in px, I must find a way to transform their width in percents dynamically..

Comment: If you're in a CMS or some other environment with code constraints you need to make that clear in your question.

Comment: This would be a case where !important could be used to overwrite the inline styles, although I'm unclear as to a situation where this would occur.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it is right in your problem statement. Just use the percentage.

```
#colA {
    width: 62.5%;
}
```

and so on...